# How to convert dictionary with list to dataframe with default index and column names

Tags: pandas

How to convert dictionary to dataframe with default index and column names

dictionary `d = {0: [1, 'Sports', 222], 1: [2, 'Tools', 11], 2: [3, 'Clothing', 23]}`

```
df

   id   type    value
0  1   Sports   222
1  2   Tools    11
2  3   Clothing 23
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame(d,index=['id','sports','clothing']).T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with `orient='index'` parameter:

```
d = {0: [1, 'Sports', 222], 1: [2, 'Tools', 11], 2: [3, 'Clothing', 23]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['id','type','value'])
print (df)
   id      type  value
0   1    Sports    222
1   2     Tools     11
2   3  Clothing     23
```